# PhpStorm highlights output option "clean" as invalid option in webpack config

Tags: javascript, webpack, phpstorm

PhpStorm shows me following tooltip text on specifiying `clean: true` in my webpack.config.js.

> webpack: Property 'clean' is not allowed
> Inspection info: Validates options in the webpack configuration file (which name should start with `webpack`, e.g. `webpack.config.js`) against [webpack Options Schema](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/master/schemas/WebpackOptions.json).
>
> Disable this inspection to turn off validation and code completions inside the configuration object.

Disabling is no option for me ;-)

I inspected the options schema and found the property 'clean'. As far as i understand the schema, it should be correct.

Here my `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/app.js',
    output: {
        clean: true,
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    mode: "development",
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Output Management',
        }),
    ],
};
```

Versions:
Webpack: 5.24.3
PhpStorm: 2020.3.2

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bundled webpack schema needs to be updates, please vote for [WEB-49925](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49925) to be notified on any progress with it

Comment: Thanks @lena for creating the issue and pointing me to it. Can you explain in more detail, what goes wrong here? I mean, the link goes to the correct webpack schema, but PhpStorm uses its own bundled schema under the lid?

Comment: exactly - PhpStorm doesn't fetch the schema from the web, it uses the one bundled with *JavascriptLanguage* plugin